# Setup new connection in mysql workbench using standard TCP IP over SSH

Tags: connection, mysql-workbench, file-permissions, ssh-keys, user-permissions

Could not read the contents of .ssh directory.

Error opening directory '/home/[username]/.ssh': Permission denied

I can see in the list of running processes that mysql-workbench is not running as root user.

I am not sure what the actual issue is. I only want to load '/home/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa' file while adding parameter in 'SSH key file' during connection setup. So that my connection should be established successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're on Ubuntu. I had this problem too and https://askubuntu.com/a/1271919/48214 was the solution for me.